# Replace looping with recursion

Tags: php, optimization, loops, recursion

I want to ask , how to make php code for php function fibonacci with recursive. Without "for" looping. I have code like this, How about without 'for' ? 
Thanks guys,,

```
<?php function fibo($n){
if($n==0)
    return 0;
elseif($n==1)
    return 1;
else
    $tambah=fibo($n-1)+fibo($n-2);
    return $tambah;
    }

for($n=0;$n<15;$n++){
    echo fibo($n)."<br/>";}
```

Comment: A while loop? It's not clear what your asking.

Comment: You already have a recursive definition. Also if optimizing your code is what you are interested in, recursion in PHP is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The way I read the question, he wants to know how to use recursion to replace loops. Keep in mind that in some programming languages, you have no choice but to use recursion to loop because theres no such things as a loop construct.

Answer (score 1):

```
function repeat($func, $times) {
    if ($times <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    $func($times);
    repeat($func, $times - 1);
}

$f = function($n) {
    echo fibo($n)."<br/>";
};

repeat($f, 15);
```

demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/F9TKPS

Comment: probably because i posted untested code that didnt work :) it works now.

Comment: @kellax Yes, but this solution is nicely general.

Comment: Added +1 to even out for a good anwser.